Pytorch TransformerEncoder: How to determine most important input features?
This is the model I use to determine the likelihood of a specific event based on input data:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
class Trnsfrmr(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        d_model=500,
        nhead=10,
        dim_feedforward=2048,
        num_layers=6,
        dropout=0.1
    ):

        super().__init__()

        encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=d_model,
            nhead=nhead,
            dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward,
            dropout=dropout,
        )
        self.transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(
            encoder_layer,
            num_layers=num_layers,
        )
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(d_model, d_model // 2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear( d_model // 2, 1 ),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
        self.d_model = d_model

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.transformer_encoder( x )
        x = self.classifier(x)

        return x

Now I am wondering how I can determine the most important input features, In this case, I have 570 input features, that lead to the output decision? For example, if the output probability is close to 1 - how do I know which input features led the network the make this prediction?
